# how to correctly use a CoordinatorLayout to collapse a list header (without toolbar)

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to implement a simple parallax header with a recyclerview.

Nothing fancy here. Just following docs, blogs, guidelines and even stackoverflow answers. But everyone just copied the doc and implemented this with a toobar. I dont want a toolbar here. And it's not working out of the box with a CoordinatorLayout. Existing solutions includes adding a fake header item to the RecyclerView, or use a header with ListView. This seems old fashioned and obsoleted by the CoordinatorLayout architecture.

If i understood correctly, the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` can only be used in the direct hierarchy of an `AppBarLayout`. That's why it's not working.
I found 2 classes: HeaderScrollingViewBehavior and HeaderBehavior in the support lib. But they are abstract and concrete classes are internal to AppBarLayout.

Anyone succesfully implemented custom behaviors for the CoordinatorLayout so it supports a RecyclerView and a header view at the same time ?
Can a NestedScrollView solve the problem easily ? (it seems not).

My layout used to have this hierarchy:

```
DrawerLayout  
  CoordinatorLayout  
    (include code, see below)
    LinearLayout fullscreen (for fragments)
    FrameLayout fullscreen (for popup fragments)
    AppBarLayout/Toolbar
```

"include" code hierarchy:

```
(Some stacked layouts (constraintlayout) including "ctobar")
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ctobar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/collapsibleHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ctobar"
        android:minHeight="10dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
        layout="@layout/fragment_homeroot_home_streamheader" />

    <mvxui.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout2
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/collapsibleHeader"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:MvxBind="RefreshCommand PullToRefreshCommand"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >
        <mvxui.MvxRecyclerView2
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/collapsibleHeader"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:divider="@color/accent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
            app:MvxItemTemplates="fragment_homeroot_home_streamcell_normal,fragment_homeroot_home_streamcell_unsaved"
            app:MvxBind="ItemsSource StreamCells; ItemClick FlightDetailCommand"
            />
    </mvxui.MvxSwipeRefreshLayout2>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My new layout has this hierarchy:

`CoordinatorLayout
    SwipeRefreshLayout (match_parent/match_parent, layout_behavior1: custom TBD)
        RecyclerView
    MyHeaderView (match_parent/wrap_content, layout_behavior2: custom TBD)`

What would you put in layout_behavior1/layout_behavior2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the solution myself as it seems it interested noone. Maybe it will interest some folk here. Check it [there](https://medium.com/@bigoudi/a-parallax-header-for-your-recyclerview-using-a-coordinatorlayour-behavior-android-development-22cfda5d8702) as it is quite long.